# Xml Php Warning Extra Content at end of document

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to write a droid app that sends and receives XML between the app and a web service. When I try to run the following code

```
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom = simplexml_load_file('php://input');
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);

$messages = Messages::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE reciever = '$xml->userName'");
$xmlString = "";
if($messages)
{

    foreach($messages as $message)
    {
    $ts = strtotime($message->ts);
 $xmlString=$xmlString."<Message><sender>".$message->sender."</sender><reciever>".$message->reciever."</reciever><timestamp>"."123"."</timestamp><text>".$message->text."</text></Message>";
    }
}
else
{
    //do something
}
$xmlReturn = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xmlReturn->loadXML($xmlString);
echo($xmlReturn->saveXML());
?>
```

I get a Warning Extra content at the end of the document.

The error comes from this line:   `$xmlReturn->loadXML($xmlString);`

I'm not 100% sure that you can create an xml document by loading a string, but I've seen similar things done and if you look [here](http://softeng.cs.uwosh.edu/students/cs342g6/index.php) you can see what it ouputs, which looks like valid XML to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XML document can have only one root element. You are stringing together multiple `<message>…</message>` combinations here, so a root element encapsulating those is missing.

Comment: Genius... this was the answer to the problem.  It lacked a root node